# how can I deploy a python script that runs 24/7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to the deployment process of python, I have been reading about things like Docker (I know a little bit about Docker) but I haven't really found any concrete guides to deploying python scripts. (I see a lot of examples for flask applications and django applications) My exact use case is a Kafka Consumer that needs to run 24/7. Would I just drop my project on an EC2 and run the docker command or the python script from the command line? if not how can I deploy my python script?

edit: I have tried writing a Dockerfile that just runs my script. Which means I would just drop my project on an EC2 and run the docker file? This sounds wrong to me, but im not entirely sure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently, I have written a Dockerfile that just runs my script. Which means I would just drop my project on an EC2 and run the docker file? This sounds wrong to me, but im not entirely sure.